# Shutting down a computer over the LAN

Tags: command-line, windows, networking, shutdown

I want a command to shut down a computer on my LAN network that is running Windows 7 and has no password set.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can install VNC or use a Remote Administration Tool (RAT).

Comment: Try `shutdown -i`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is writting this command in the Terminal.

`net rpc SHUTDOWN -C “some comment here” -f -I x.x.x.x -U user_name%password` (where x.x.x.x is your Windows IP).

Comment: if there is no password what to do?? and what “some comment here” mean ???

Comment: "Some Comment Here" is a placeholder for you to actually specify within quotes the reason for the shutdown.  In this case, if the reason was for maintenance, you could use "Shutdown for Scheduled Maintenance" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Enable [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) on Windows then use **Remote Desktop Viewer** ([`vinagre`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinagre)) on Ubuntu to connect to your Windows machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could install [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/downloads) (or enable Remote Desktop) on the Windows PC, then login and shut down the PC.

Another way would be to install the telnet server for Windows. This will allow you to telnet into the Windows machine and send a shut down command.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use the FOR command combined with shutdown.

```
FOR /L %i in (1,1,254) DO shutdown ''192.168.0.%i
```

Where `192.168.0.%i` is, fill in the IP of the machine you want to shut down. Leaving it in this form will shutdown all computers on the network.

You can download a GUI [version here](http://www.petri.co.il/software/shutdown.zip).

[image]